# SWIFT - How to compare instance of an array typed with Protocol

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift code and sorry for my bad english.
Here is my code:

```
var t = Array<MyClassProtocol> ()
var instance1 = MyClasse () //protocol MyClassProtocol
var instance2 = MyClasse () //protocol MyClassProtocol 
var instance3 = MyClasse2 () //protocol MyClassProtocol 
t.append (instance1)
t.append (instance2)
t.append (instance3)

//What I try to do 

for instance in t
{
    if (instance === instance1){ /* do something */ }
}
```

> XCode return : type MyClassProtocol does not conform to protocol
>   "AnyObject"

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Can we also see the classes MyClasse and MyClasse2

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator can be applied only to instances of classes. However, Swift doesn't have only classes, it also has structs. Structs can also adopt `MyClassProtocol`. The problem is that when Swift sees `instance` only as a `MyClassProtocol`, it doesn't know whether it is a struct or a class, so you cannot use `===`.

To solve it, you need to prevent `MyClassProtocol` from being adopted by structs. This is done by letting it inherit from `AnyObject` (which is an empty class protocol).

```
protocol MyClassProtocol : AnyObject {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let MyClassProtocol inherit from AnyObject

```
protocol MyClassProtocol : AnyObject {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you MyclassProtocol not inherit from AnyObject. 
so try this: it is maybe work.

```
protocol MyClassProtocol:AnyObject{ // make sure  you protocol inherit from AnyObject
 func doSomething()
} 




class Myclass:MyClassProtocol{
 func doSomething() {

 }
}

class Myclass2: MyClassProtocol {
 func doSomething() {

 }
} 
var t = Array<MyClassProtocol>()
var instance1 = Myclass () //protocol MyClassProtocol
var instance2 = Myclass () //protocol MyClassProtocol
var instance3 = Myclass2 () //protocol MyClassProtocol
t.append (instance1)
t.append (instance2)
t.append (instance3)


for instance in t{
  if (instance === instance1){

 }
}
```

Comment: It works ! Thank u very much. It's simple when u know !

Answer (score -1):

Your classes will need to implement the protocol MyClassProtocol

e.g.

```
class MyClasse: NSObject, MyClassProtocol
                          ^ Here we tell the class that it should implement the protocol
```

Just as an aside, you can also declare your arrays like this:

```
var t : [MyClassProtocol] = [];
```